# Foursquare API " Get Next Venues" - error 'Endpoint not found'

Tags: python, api, foursquare

## Foursquare.getNextVenues python

I am getting 'Endpoint not found' error when I try the 'Get Next Venues' (https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/api/venues/nextvenues).

Any idea why this is doesn't work? Thanks in advance!

#### code:

```
import requests # library to handle requests

VENUE_ID = '4d14cf30401db60cdf4ddba4'

url = 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/{}/nextvenues/search?client_id={}&client_secret={}&v={}'.format(
        VENUE_ID,
        CLIENT_ID,
        CLIENT_SECRET,
        VERSION)

results = requests.get(url).json()
```

#### Output is:

```
{
    "meta": {
        "code": 404,
        "errorType": "other",
        "errorDetail": "Endpoint not found",
        "requestId": "5ca6fc44351e3d25e5d1da14"
    },
    "response": {}
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved. My url syntax was wrong. Correct syntax is without 'search'.